# Unable to Ping Windows Machine connected in the same LAN on WiFi

Tags: windows-10, networking, ping

I have two machines which is connected to the same LAN. From Machine(B), I am able to Ping Machine(A) successfully. However from Machine(A), I couldn't Ping Machine(B).

Machine(A): Windows 10 Enterprise IP Address: 192.168.1.37

Machine(B): Windows 10 Enterprise IP Address: 192.168.1.36

Router IP Address: 192.168.1.1 (Able to Ping this from both the machines successfully)

**From Machine(A) to Machine(B):**

```
>ping 192.168.1.36

Pinging 192.168.1.36 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.36:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

**Additional Note:** I thought destination host filters ICMP ping requests on its Local Firewall and verified the Incoming Rules on the Destination Host and can confirm the ping requests are allowed. Please find the screenshots below.

[image: Incoming Firewall Rules in the Destination Host]

## Update 1:

- Both the Machines are on WIFI on Same Network.
- Both the Machines are on Public Profile.
- In the Both the Machines Network Discovery & File / Printer Sharing is turned on.

**Machine(A): routes**

```
>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 39...f0 77 c3 97 5b 72 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 31...f2 77 c3 97 5b 71 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 14...f0 77 c3 97 5b 71 ......Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.37     55
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.37    311
     192.168.1.37  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.37    311
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.37    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.37    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.37    311
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 14    311 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    311 fe80::74d6:7f44:7253:24ad/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    311 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

**ipconfig:**

```
>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hgu_lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::74d6:7f44:7253:24ad%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.37
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

**Machine(B): routes:**

```
>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
  2...0a 11 22 33 44 56 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 12...08 11 22 33 44 55 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
  8...0a 11 22 33 44 55 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.36     50
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.36    306
     192.168.1.36  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.36    306
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.36    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.36    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.36    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

**ipconfig:**

```
>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hgu_lan
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.36
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

## Update 2:

- Please take a look at the below screenshot and the highlighted section. Is that an issue?

[image]

Comment: Questions: Are all connections the same - Ethernet or WiFi? Things to try: (1) On B do `ping 127.0.0.1`. Does it work? (2) On A try `ping google.com`. (3) Enter the `route` command on A & B and add the outputs to your post. The output of `ipconfig` would also help.

Comment: Do you have Network Discovery turned OFF?  If either/both network adapters are wireless, do you have them set to Public?

Comment: Both the Machines are on Public Profile.  .... Try setting this to Private.  Normally Public turns Network Discovery off, so I am not sure about this.

Comment: The only problem is, From Machine(A) I am not able to Ping Machine(B). I have tried changing the Profiles to Private/Public and vice versa. It didn't help.

Comment: On the machine you cannot Ping, open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator, run DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW, restart and test.

Comment: @John tried your suggestion but no luck yet.

Comment: Can my Outbound Traffic block the connection too? Is there a easy way to verify it?

Comment: On the problem machine, can you set the Windows Firewall to default?  Then restart the computer and test.